# What if I have more than a few questions?

Tags: discussion

What if I have more than a few questions about a chapter in a book, say?

I have tried asking them separately, ending up making at least 5 threads.
But I don't think it is an effective use of online space here.

It should be permitted to post multiple questions about a specific chapter or article.

I think there are two types of questions.
One is the type that comes to you and can be asked separately from books or articles.
The other is the type that comes to you from articles or books and can't be asked separately without making more than a few threads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One post per question. It's hard to be more helpful than that without seeing an example, but here’s a shot at it.

Suppose you are asking about a grammatical construct you see in several places in the same book. That’s one question.

On the other hand, asking about three quite different things, that’s three questions, even though they all came up because you were reading one book.

Also, if you are reading a book written in modern English and many questions are coming up, it could be that you are an English language learner and should consider taking advantage of the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) community.